# Ideal, integral domain, PID, prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am very confused with above terms, can anyone please show me examples and/or a good way to remember and understand their differences? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you go on a Wikipedia and draw the relationships out for yourself. An ideal is a subring that absorbs all elements of the ring. A principal ideal is one generated by a single element, a principle ideal domain is a domain in which all ideals are principle

Comment: This is sort of like asking about the difference between snake, zoo, terrarium, cobra. (Not a perfect analogy, but still...)

Comment: @HansLundmark I think if snakes are ideals then terrarium should be replaced with something like worm tank, to preserve the "long wriggly thing" analogy

Comment: In order to explain, I would have to use words, but it sounds like until now words have not sufficed to convey meaning to you.  My advice is to look at the words more and understand their meaning, or at least find the point where the words stop making sense, and then tell us what those words are, so we can make another attempt with different using different words to convey meaning to you. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *integral domain* is a commutative ring $R$ such that if $ab = 0$, then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ for all $a,b \in R$. This is equivalent to the statement that $0$ is the only zero-divisor. This is not true in general - consider $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$. Neither $4$, nor $6$ are $0$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$, yet $6 \cdot 4 = 24 = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$.

A *principal ideal domain* (PID) is an integral domain in which every ideal is principal. (I define what it means to be a principal ideal below.)

An *ideal* $I$ is a subgroup of the additive group of a ring $R$ that is closed under multiplication with respect to *all* the elements of the ring. In symbols, $\forall r \in R$ $rI \subseteq I$. For an example, let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and consider $d\mathbb{Z}$ for any $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

(Two-sided) ideals are important because they are precisely the subsets of a ring $R$ that you can use to quotient the ring to get a well-defined *quotient ring* $R/I$. This is similar to the idea of quotient groups (which you should be familiar with.)

There are subtleties here - most people only ever deal with two-sided ideals, but ideals can also be exclusively left-sided or right-sided. You can only factor rings with two-sided ideals. You can look up the difference on Wikipedia.

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is said to be *prime* if $ab \in I$ implies that either $a \in I$ or $b \in I$. Equivalently, $R/I$ is an *integral domain*.

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is said to be *principal* if $I = aR$ for some $a \in R$.

I hope that helps clarify the difference.